# While loop not breaking out

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
selection = input.nextInt();
while (selection != 1 || selection != 2 || selection != 3 || selection != 4){
    System.out.println("*");
    selection = input.nextInt(); 
}
```

The above code just goes into a loop no matter what I enter it just repeats itself. I'm probably making a silly mistake somewhere but I can't see it probably due to lack of sleep. Any help is welcome, thanks.

All the or signs have been changed to && signs but it still keeps looping?

Comment: When should the loop exit? When you changed all `||` by `&&` it will exit e.g. when selection is `1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
while (selection != 1 || selection != 2 || selection != 3 || selection != 4)
```

by

```
while (selection != 1 && selection != 2 && selection != 3 && selection != 4)
```

selection != 1 || selection != 2`is always`true`because`selection` cannot be not 1 and be not 2.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Thanks!

Comment: @subirkumarsao that's not [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeMorgan%27s_Law).

Comment: Depends on wwhen you want to leave the loop. My `&&`-Version leaves the loop, if selection is 1,2,3 or 4.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thats exactly what I want but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1861156: Loop.condition worked fine in a test on my computer. I used the values `7, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1` and the loop exited after `5`.

Comment: Thank you, It's probably to due with the switch statement because I have it in the default part to keep it looping. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is always true. For any number you pick, it's always not 1 *or* not 2. 1 *is* equal to 1, but it's not equal to 2, so the condition is true, likewise 2 is not equal to 1 so the condition is true. Every other number isn't equal to 1 *or* 2, so the condition is still true.

Answer (score 1):

`while` will execute the block unless the expression false.  `selection != 1 || selection != 2` is always true.

I think you want to change `!=` to `==` or better yet

```
while (0 < selection && selection <= 4)
```